# Python - how to see and modify Import Path (FileUtil module can not be found)

Tags: python, docker, import, path, jython

I have a script in jython (basically Python code) that has a module 'FileUtil' all wrapped into a docker..

On some machines - it works fine and on other machines (with same exact docker images) - it is complaining that `FileUtil` module can not be found.

How to check paths and imports during a run in Python?

(or how to force preparing environment for docker so that it always has `FileUtil` module?)

Answer (score 0):

You have to append the directory of the `FileUtil` module to the `sys.path`. Example (assuming `FileUtil` resides in `C:\Modules`):

```
Import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Modules")
Import FileUtil
```

Comment: Thanks.. How to see which folders / paths are accessible when starting a Python script (just to make sure about current environment). Something like: `print sys.path`?

Comment: Found it: ```import sys
for el in sys.path:
 print(el)```